# Converting a BASH script to Python problem

Tags: python, bash

I have the following bash script I've been trying to convert to python. I have the main part but I'm having some trouble on how to translate these two lines `cut=${auth#*<ChallengeCode>}` and `authStr=${cut%</ChallengeCode>*}`. The first request returns XML that contains `<ChallengeCode>` , I need to be able to extract that code and store it for future use.

**BASH CODE:**

```
#!/bin/bash
IP=IP_ADDR
USER=USERNAME
PASS=PASSWORD

auth=$(curl -ks -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -c "cookies.txt" "https://${IP}/goform/login?cmd=login&user=admin&type=1")
cut=${auth#*<ChallengeCode>}
authStr=${cut%</ChallengeCode>*}
hash=$(echo -n ${authStr}:GDS3710lZpRsFzCbM:${PASS} | md5sum | tr -d '/n')
hash=$(echo $hash | cut -d' ' -f1 | tr -d '/n')
curl -ks -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -c "cookies.txt" "https://${IP}/goform/login?cmd=login&user=admin&authcode=${hash}&type=1"
curl -ks -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" --cookie "cookies.txt" "https://${IP}/snapshot/view0.jpg" >> snapshot.jpg
```

**PYTHON CODE:**

```
import requests
import hashlib

hmd5 = hashlib.md5()

ip = "192.168.100.178"
user = "admin"
password = "Password1"

auth = requests.get('https://{0}/goform/login', headers=headers, params=params, verify=False).format(ip)

chcode = (This is where I want to put the challenge code i get back from the previous request)

hstring = "{0}:GDS3710lZpRsFzCbM:{1}".format(chcode,password).encode() 
hmd5.update(hstring)

hashauth = hmd5.hexdigest()

response = requests.get('https://{0}/snapshot/view0.jpg', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, verify=False).format(ip)
```

Any advice on how I could better improve the code would also be appreciated.

Comment: `'https://',ip,'/goform/login'` that is 3 arguments. You need `format`: `"https://{}/goform/login".format(ip)`

Comment: Stack Overflow's format is well-suited to narrow questions about very specific problems; we ask that any code not necessary for someone else to reproduce the specific problem you're asking about be removed, as described in the [mcve] definition and the "Tricks for Trimming" section of http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your request returns XML, it'd be suitable to use a XML parser. Presuming you've imported `xml.etree.ElementTree` perhaps with:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

You can have it parse your response:

```py
root_el = ET.fromstring(auth.text)
```

And then use XPath (might be different depending on structure of your XML) to find your element and get value of text it contains:

```py
chcode = root_el.find("./ChallengeCode").text
```

Answer (score 1):

While one of the virtues of a real programming language is the availability of powerful libraries (*e.g.*, for parsing XML), there is a direct analog of your Bash substring operations that is particularly simple given the limited use of wildcards:

```
${a#*foo} — a.partition("foo")[0]
${a%foo*} — a.rpartition("foo")[-1]
${a##*foo} — a.rpartition("foo")[0]
${a%%foo*} — a.partition("foo")[-1]
```